# What is the reason of "An item with the same key has already been added." message in vs?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, devexpress

I am using Devexpress' DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport component. And in vs2008 pro sp1, when i try to add a dataset to the report, it waits a while and then says:"Error message: An item with the same key has already been added". What might be the possible reasons with this problem and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Something in the report is using a Hashtable where the Key it is using for the Hashtable is added twice.  Possibly your dataset has a column that is being used as a key, and has data in it that is not unique?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Finally i have figured out. I had been added InteropServices.dll reference twice somewhere in the project as it didn't seem so in the solution panel. I've removed the reference and re-added. That's ok now. ;)